# A floor function sum involving $\lfloor n/d\rfloor$ and related to sums of divisors

Tags: number-theory

Consider the well known identity from elementary number theory:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \tau(k)=\sum_{d=1}^n \left\lfloor \frac{n}{d} \right\rfloor,$$
where of course the asymptotic expression for both sides is $n \log n + (2\gamma-1) n + O(\sqrt{n}).$

Some experimentation with Maple seems to show that if $v:=\frac{n}{\log n},$ then
$$
F(v):=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{d=1}^{\lfloor v\rfloor} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{d} \right\rfloor }{\sum_{d=1}^n \left\lfloor \frac{n}{d} \right\rfloor },\quad (1)
$$
is increasing towards $1$ from below.

Is it possible to prove what the limit in (1) is, if $v=c\frac{n}{\log n},$ for some $c \in (0,1)$?

Comment: The difference between the top and the bottom should not be far from n(log((log n)/c)-1).  Gerhard "Is This Estimate Close Enough?" Paseman, 2017.01.24.

Comment: As @GerhardPaseman says, this seems straightforward: $1-F(\nu)$ is the ratio of the sum from $\nu$ to $n$ divided by the sum from $1$ to $n$. You already have an estimate for the sum from $1$ to $n$, so you just need to prove the sum from $\nu$ to $n$ is of smaller order (which you can do by estimating the terms in the sum).

Comment: Thanks, I will have a go at it and try to formulate an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit can be estimated via (recalling $v=\frac{c n}{\log n}$):
$$
1-F(v)=\frac{\sum_{d=\lfloor v \rfloor +1}^n \lfloor \frac{n}{d} \rfloor}
{\sum_{d=1}^n \lfloor \frac{n}{d} \rfloor}
\geq \frac{(n-\frac{cn}{\log n})\log n}{n \log n + (2\gamma-1)n+O(\sqrt{n})}
\sim 1-c(\log n)^{-1}
$$
by upper bounding the top of the numerator by number of terms times the largest term of the sum.